# Jenkins, JFrog and Jira installations on one server

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, jira, devops, jfrog-cli

can we able to install Jenkins, Jfrog and Jira in a same one server? i tried installing Jenkins & JFrog initially and then installed Jira. after installing Jira, Jfrog is not accessible from web interface.

Comment: There should not be any restriction as such.  As long you configure unique ports for all the products and have enough resources.  Are you installing docker installers?

Comment: There would be much better if you showed any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins default port is 8080

Jira default port is 8080.

Two applications cant run on the same port. Moreover each application should have its own dedicated port.

If you didnt modify the default port during installation. then you are facing a busy port issue.

In Jira you can modify the port that Jira uses by following this:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/changing-jira-application-tcp-ports-938847762.html

If you modify Jira port to something else, let's say 8081, then Jenkins should run normally on port 8080.

Note, keep in mind port changes only take effect when you restart the application.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can but it will be hard to work out which one is causing you performance problems later on